# The difference between "hu" and "zeh"

Tags: words, tanach, translation

In Yeshayahu, 42:8, the text reads

> אֲנִ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה ה֣וּא שְׁמִ֑י

This is translated in most English version I can find as

"I am God, THAT is my name."

The targum doesn't translate it at all.

But the word "hu" generally is a third person masculine pronoun, "he" and the word "zeh" seems to be used for "this" or "that". According to [this](https://myhebrewwords.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/6-%D7%96%D7%94-zeh-this-and-that/) website, the difference between the two is also

> a word to indicate something that is near – זה – and a word to indicate something which is far – הוא –

That page also reads

> In Midrash, the Rabbis try to read extra meaning into the words of the Torah. The Rabbis usually don’t read the word זה as referring to something abstract. Instead, they will use their powers of interpretation to explain that זה refers to something concrete which is actually present. This is because זה indicates something near – so you need to find what that near thing is.

but in the case of Sh'mot 3:15, the text reads

> זֶה־שְּׁמִ֣י

and in [other](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.25.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) cases, the reference to Hashem through the 4 letter name is with the word "zeh."

Why then is the 4 letter name sometimes referred to via "hu" and sometimes through "zeh" (and, secondarily, why would every translation, including "[Jewish](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15973)" ones, use "that" and not "he")?